# Удаление элементов

Tags: javascript

А как удалять такие элементы?

```
var player = document.createElement("audio");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
const player = document.createElement('audio');
document.body.appendChild(player);
// удаление
document.body.removeChild(player);
```

Comment: Или чуть проще: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove